# How to keep precision entered by users?

Tags: java

I want to create a calculator. For illustration purposes, let me simplify the problem as follows.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.MathContext;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;

public class NumberFormating {
    public static void main(String[] argas) {
        List<String> sInputs = new ArrayList<String>();

        sInputs.add("12345.67890");
        sInputs.add("12345678901234.5");
        sInputs.add("123456789012.345");
        sInputs.add("1234567890.12345");
        sInputs.add("123456.789012435");
        sInputs.add("1.23456789012345");
        sInputs.add("0.00123456789012");
        sInputs.add("0.0012345");

        for (String s : sInputs) {
            BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(s);
            number = number.round(new MathContext(15, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));

            DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
            symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');

            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##", symbols);

            System.out.println(df.format(number));
        }
        System.out.println("==== END ====");
    }
}
```

I want to get outputs with **digit grouping** and **original precision** typed by users.
Maximum precision is 15.

The unexpected results (left) and expected result (right) are given as follows:

```
12 345.68            --> 12 345.67890
12 345 678 901 234.5 --> 12 345 678 901 234.5
123 456 789 012.34   --> 123 456 789 012.345
1 234 567 890.12     --> 1 234 567 890.12345
123 456.79           --> 123 456.789012435
1.23                 --> 1.23456789012345
0                    --> 0.00123456789012
0                    --> 0.0012345
```

Please how to achieve such a requirement?

Bonus: If you can implement digit grouping for the fraction part (digit after decimal point), it will be much much nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above results you get because you defined the `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##", symbols);` for two decimal points. You can use something like this to get the results you want,

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.###############", symbols);
```

Comment: Using this solution the last "0" from the first number is lost, so you don't get the exact expected result from the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you limited your decimals to only 2 places.
If you know that there might be 15 digits, just set it in `DecimalFormat`
like this:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.###############", symbols);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The first answer wins as the accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you already finished the part of grouping 3 digits as a group. The remain part I think here is the solution. Assume that n is from input.

```java
int n = 0;
String s = "%" + n.toString() + ".f"
System.out.printf(s, number)
```

In your last case, if you user enter 2, it must be 0.00 (I think so)